# how to Read File/Directory Version/Revision from Remote SVN Tree?

Tags: svn

is there any way to read Properys from a remote SVN Location ?

i want to JUST read the version number of a single file in a remote repro wothout have them synced.

the only thing i found so far is "SVN INFO"

i simply make a grep now on "Revision", but this is not really a smart way to do this.

Comment: one problem with "svn info" is that it reply the Revision of the Whole Repro and not the Revision of the pointed file

Answer (score 0):

svn info should work

Try svn info http://host/the/location/of/your/file

it should give you information containing

```
Path: file
Name: file
URL: http://host/the/location/of/your/file
Repository Root: http://host/the
Repository UUID: balbalbal-blabalbal
Revision: 2
Node Kind: file
Last Changed Author: someone
Last Changed Rev: 2
Last Changed Date: 2010-07-16 10:34:18 +0800 (Fri, 16 Jul 2010)
```

Last Changed Rev is what you need

Comment: yes it works ... i dont know what i did wrong before .. (it has returned always the same revision number) ... thanks alot.